# Operator '=' is not defined for 'Nothing' and type 'OleDbCommand'

Tags: vb.net

need yours help for below coding, im trying to create the login form at vb.net but system show the error    **"Operator '=' is not defined for 'Nothing' and type 'OleDbCommand'."**

below is my coding

```
enter code here


    Dim MyOledbCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand()

    If MyCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Login WHERE username = '" & txtuser.Text & "' and password ='" & _
                                 txtpass.Text & "'", OleDbConn) Then
        MsgBox("Login Success")
        Form1.Show()
    Else
        MsgBox("Login Failed")

    End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new `OleDbCommand` isn't actually going to *execute* it at all, nor is it a valid condition for an `If` statement. I suspect you want something like:

```
Dim sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Login WHERE username = ? and password = ?"
Dim count As Integer
Using command As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, OleDbConn)
    command.Parameters.Add("@User", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtuser.Text
    command.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtpass.Text
    count = CInt(command.ExecuteScalar())
End Using

If count > 0 Then
    MsgBox("Login Success")
    Form1.Show()
Else
    MsgBox("Login Failed")
```

The *exact* syntax may be slightly off (I'm not a VB programmer) but the gist of it should be okay. Notes:

- I'm using a `Using` statement so that the command is disposed automatically at the end of the block. You should do the same for your connection.... if you're trying to keep the same connection open for the whole program, you shouldn't. Let the connection pool manage that.
- I'm using parameterized SQL instead of putting the values directly into the SQL. This is important to avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Even if this is only a toy project, you should get into the habit of parameterized SQL straight away.
- I'm selecting the *count* of rows rather than the rows themselves. We only need to know if there are any valid users matching the criteria.
- You shouldn't be doing this (or any other database work) in the UI thread. Use a `BackgroundWorker` or asynchronous methods.
- You should **never** store passwords in plaintext as it appears you are here. I really hope this is a toy app, as it's desperately insecure at the moment. Again, try to get into good habits early.